# How to write text in <area>, <shape> tags

Tags: html, webview, shapes, area

I have a .png image with a map.

[image: map]

And there is html code responsible for getting each area.

```
<area shape="poly" coords="728,810,782,810,782,932,728,932"
href="/navigator/15/16" title="Posud Meister"> 
<area shape="poly"   coords="912,220,912,268,874,268,874,220" 
href="/navigator/13/19"   title="Attribute">
<area shape="poly" coords="1098,332,1074,332,1074,348,1098,348" 
href="/navigator/13/21" title="Something1">
<area shape="poly"   coords="1098,332,1074,332,1074,348,1098,348" 
href="/navigator/15/21"   title="Something2">
```

and so on...
When I hover over the certain shape it pops-up the title like "Something1" etc. I want to use this map in WebViews in Android, iOS, Windows Phone, and so I want this text to always be there. How can I add text to the certain shape? Is this possible?

Comment: Open the image in MS Paint, add the text to it. Or would that be too easy?

Comment: that's surely the way but there are more than one image; more over they are probable to change. changing the images every time is not the best solution i guess?

Comment: OK, so you need some Javascript to fetch all `area` elements, check their `coords`, calculate the middle of the X and Y values, and put the text of each `title` attribute in those positions by creating new elements and positioning these over the map in the right position. Sounds doable...